How to set an Open Telemetry's span id to a custom value in C++
Does anyone know how, in C++, to 1) create an Open Telemetry span with a custom span id taken from a hex string generated by someone else, or 2) set the span id of an existing span to a custom value, or 3) overwrite the default span id generated by the otel library for a new span with a custom value (taken from a hex string generated elsewhere)?
Preferably, the solution should not involve re-implementing all the functionality of an abstract Span class. It should be something short and sweet.
I have figured out how to 1) set the new span's Trace Id from a hex string generated by someone else and 2) how to set the new span's Parent Span Id from a hex string generated by someone else. All of this can be done via the StartSpanOptions class.
However, at the moment I cannot find any C++ examples of how to set just the span id of a new span to a custom value from a hex string generated elsewhere.

In the Open Telemetry's GitHub repo, in the sdk/source/trace/span.h file, I can see how they do just that - but the problem with this is that they do not expose that particular Span class for the public consumption.

Any help with this matter will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Not really sure how this will help because there are no issues, coredumps or any other coding problems per se with this other than a total absence of working C++ examples. But OK. Here:
TraceId             traceId =
                    opentelemetry::trace::propagation::
                    B3Propagator::TraceIdFromHex( traceIdStr );

SpanId              parentSpanId =
                    opentelemetry::trace::propagation::
                    B3Propagator::SpanIdFromHex( parentSpanIdStr );

startSpanOpts.parent = 
                    SpanContext( traceId, parentSpanId, TraceFlags( 0x01 ), true );

startSpanOpts.kind = SpanKind::kClient;
startSpanOpts.start_system_time = myStartSystemTimePoint;
startSpanOpts.start_steady_time = myStartSteadyTimePoint;

auto        span = tracer->StartSpan( "myAwesomeSpan", startSpanOpts );

The code above compiles without warnings, links, runs, works as advertised.
All is good. Except that the id of span was auto-generated by the otel c++ library and I need that id to be set from a custom hex string generated elsewhere, such that if the following code is executed:
span->GetContext().span_id().ToLowerBase16( spanId );

then the contents of the spanId variable match the contents of the custom hex string.
Any ideas how to accomplish that?
Thanks.

I'm going to be optimistic and based on probability, yes, there is a person who can do items 1, 2, and 3.

You would get better quality help if you posted your attempt as a plain text [mcve] and indicate where you are having issues.  Running a debugger before you post would be an extremely good idea.

Just added a working code example to the bottom of my question. Thanks.
